# Determine the value of a function evaluated at its inverse

Tags: functions

[image]

That is, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, $a>0$, the restricted function $f\upharpoonright:(-\infty,a]\rightarrow \text{range}(f)$ is invertible, and the shifted function $g(x):=f(x+a)$ is even.

If $c>a$ what is $f^{-1}(f(c))$?

I am unsure how to approach this question?

Comment: I'd start with defining what means that $f(x+a)$ is even, that should get you started.

Comment: I feel like the statement is not complete. What is f ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the statement "The continuous function $f(x+a)$ is even" means that the function $g(x):= f(x+a)$ is even (and defined on the interval $(-\infty, 0]$).  In this case, the graph of $g(x)$ is the graph of $f(x)$ shifted to the left by $a$.

Putting $\Delta:=c-a$ we have
$$f(c)=f(a+\Delta)=g(\Delta)=g(-\Delta)=f(a-\Delta)$$

Since the restricted function $f \upharpoonright (-\infty, a]$ is invertible and $(a-\Delta)$ is in the interval $(-\infty,a]$, $f^{-1}(f(a-\Delta))=(a-\Delta)$.  Combining this with the line above gives
$$f^{-1}(f(c))=f^{-1}(f(a-\Delta))=(a-\Delta) = 2a-c.$$